# get time from long format

Tags: c#, date, time

I want to time from this type string

30-12-1899 14:32:54

```
string ReportTime = JobReportTime.Substring(9, 19);
```

but when I use Substring give me error "Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count"

Comment: You can split it and get the second token JobReportTime.Split(" ")[1]

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using .Substring() instead of a cleaner way to get the date???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring arguments are start position and length, not start and end index.  You could use `.Substring(11, 8)` but as Substring will just return the rest of the string if you don't specify a length, `.Substring(11)` will give you what you're after.  Of course, you should probably consider parsing the string into a `DateTime` and then extracting the time information, as others have suggested.

Comment: The start index should be `11`, with `9` he gets the last char of the year portion and the separating space.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I assumed the asker had got the first parameter correct.  Should have engaged brain :(

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter of Substring is the startIndex. In your case this would be:

```
string ReportTime = JobReportTime.Substring(11); // returns "14:32:54"
```

If the day and month parts can also be single-digit (e.g. "1-4-1899 14:32:54") then it might be safer to extract the part after the space character:

```
string ReportTime = JobReportTime.Substring(JobReportTime.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: Parsing to a valid DateTime instance would be safer still.

Comment: @Ade: absolutely agree! But if the format is well known, a string-operation is OK IMO.

Comment: Yeah, that's true enough.  If you can guarantee the format the string was written in, the string operation will be just as safe, and a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited last answer)

```
 DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("30-12-1899 14:32:54");
 string ReportTIme = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt").ToString();
```

Comment: As the OP is using `Substring` on `JobReportTime`, I'd assume that `JobReportTime` is a string, so there is no `ToString(string format)` overload.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed further functionality from it you could convert it to a DateTime:

```
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime("30-12-1899 14:32:54");
time = dt.TimeOfDay.ToString();
// returns "14:32:54"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you using [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

```
const string dateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
const string dateTimeString = "30-12-1899 14:32:54";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.TimeOfDay);
```

I think the code is a little bit cleaner: it specifies how to parse `DateTime` from string explicitly.